# Выполнять действие пока нажата кнопка

Tags: java, javafx

Нужна кнопка нажав, на которую можно выполнить действие и если кнопка зажата дальше чем, скажем, 200 мс., то выполнять действие до тех пор, пока кнопка не будет отпущена.
Но оказывается не все так просто. Я не могу просто написать в вызове что-то вроде:

```
if(pressed){
    Thread.sleep(100);
    doIt();
}
```

Это остановит поток пользовательского интерфейса. Значит это надо перенести в другой поток.

То есть, по нажатию кнопку должен создаваться новый поток, который будет следить за тем нажата ли кнопка, сколько прошло времени,выполнять нужное действие.

К тому же, обязательно придется проследить чтобы поток был завершен вместе с закрытием приложения и т.д.

Может есть другие разумные способы решить данную задачу? Идеально если бы был какой-то функционал отложенной задачи, по типу `__Platform.runLater__` , но только выполнить задачу через 100 мс, но я ничего подобного не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написал вот такую вот конструкцию.

```
private Thread pressingThread;

@FXML
void onPress() {
    System.out.println("do something");
    final int initDelay = 200;
    final int repeatDelay = 50;
    pressingThread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(initDelay);
            while (true) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> System.out.println("do something again"));
                Thread.sleep(repeatDelay);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    });
    pressingThread.setDaemon(true);
    pressingThread.start();
}

@FXML
void onRelease() {
    pressingThread.interrupt();
}
```

Создается поток, который ждет необходимое время, потом в бесконечном цикле передает управление в поток пользовательского интерфейса нужное действие. Чтобы завершить работу необходимо вызывать метод *interrupt()*.

Пробовал реализовать через переменную *pressed*, которая хранила бы состояние кнопки, и потом проверять не зажата ли кнопка, но тут есть тонкость, что если быстро нажать дважды на кнопку, то можно создать два потока, которые будут думать что кнопка не была отпущена. Потому все равно придется использовать *interrupt()*.

Ред.
Переписал в более удобный вид

```
import javafx.application.Platform;

public class DoWhilePressed {
    private int initDelay = 200;
    private int repeatDelay = 50;
    private Runnable doWhilePressed = ()->{};

    private Thread pressingThread;

    private pressed = false;
    public void press(){
        if(pressed)return;
        pressed = true;
        doWhilePressed.run();
        pressingThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(initDelay);
                while (true) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> doWhilePressed.run());
                    Thread.sleep(repeatDelay);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        });
        pressingThread.setDaemon(true);
        pressingThread.start();
    }

    public void release(){
        pressed = false;
        pressingThread.interrupt();
    }

    public int getInitDelay() {
        return initDelay;
    }

    public DoWhilePressed setInitDelay(int initDelay) {
        this.initDelay = initDelay;
        return this;
    }

    public int getRepeatDelay() {
        return repeatDelay;
    }

    public DoWhilePressed setRepeatDelay(int repeatDelay) {
        this.repeatDelay = repeatDelay;
        return this;
    }

    public Runnable getDoWhilePressed() {
        return doWhilePressed;
    }

    public DoWhilePressed setDoWhilePressed(Runnable doWhilePressed) {
        this.doWhilePressed = doWhilePressed;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Использовать можно как

```
private DoWhilePressed doWhilePressed = new DoWhilePressed()
            .setInitDelay(300)
            .setRepeatDelay(30)
            .setDoWhilePressed(() -> System.out.println("pressed"));

@FXML
void onPress() {
    doWhilePressed.press();
}

@FXML
void onRelease() {
    doWhilePressed.release();
}
```

Comment: Примерно такая структура и приходит в голову. Что бы второй поток не создавался можно при отпускании кнопки устанавливать disable На initDelay время.

Comment: @Maxim И все равно кажется, что существует где-то "правильное", простое и элегантное решение

Comment: Ну можно не создавать поток прям на месте, а отправлять событие, которое подписчик будет ловить и уже выполнять нужное задание (Publish & Subscribe Pattern).