# При удерживании кнопки появляется задержка

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, разработка-игр

Создал игру, где нужно двигаться по лабиринту персонажем. Когда удерживаешь кнопку, например,- влево, то он раз передвинулся влево, потом остановился где-то на секунду, и потом уже нормально дальше двигается. Вопрос в том, можно ли как-то убрать эту задержку?
Пример движения влево:

```
     Main.pane.getScene().addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            switch (event.getCode()){
               case A:
                    moveLeft();
                    if(keys[0]){// проверка нажата ли кнопка вверх(нужно для  
                                //движения по диагонали)
                        moveUp();
                    }
                    if(keys[1]){
                        moveDown();
                    }
                    break;
          }
        }
    });
```

Функция moveLeft:

```
 public void moveLeft(){
    if(!IsIntersected(3)){ //проверка, есть ли впереди стена
        keys[2] = true;
        rect.setX(rect.getX() - step);
        Main.pane.setLayoutX(Main.pane.getLayoutX() + step);
        dir = Direction.Left;
    }
    else{
        tpToWall(3); // если до стенки меньше шага то тогда телепортировать 
                     // к стенке
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо привязывать движение не прямо на событие клавиши. Получается, когда нажали клавишу раз, то персонаж двигается, а потом в следующий раз он задвижется только когда начнутся повторения события PRESS.
Вместо такого подхода надо только сообщать о том, что клавиша была зажата, а в основной цикле игры каждый раз проверять "если клавиша была зажата, то двигаться вверх"
Если у вас прям вообще никаких циклов нет и не хочется делать как правильно, то можете попробовать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/858970/243285). Сам написал, когда нужно было нечто похожее. Просто установите задержку перед повтором равную задержке повтора. Должно работать